# Retrieving (load)ed source code from CCL?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, ccl

I called `(load "code.lisp")` with CCL, then accidentally deleted code.lisp. Is there any way for me to retrieve the source code? Does CCL have it in memory anywhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a very special functionality. Here only for **Clozure CL**. The code won't work anywhere else. This works for me in the CCL IDE. It retrieves the source code of symbols who are `:internal` or `:external` in a certain package. It doesn't do that for symbols which are inherited from other packages (you would then often have the source code from the package `CL` or `CCL`, which is a bit too much).

```
(defun retrieve-source-code (&optional (package *package*))
  (do-symbols (s package)
    (multiple-value-bind (symbol where)
                         (find-symbol (symbol-name s)
                                      package)
      (declare (ignore symbol))
      (when (member where '(:internal :external))
        (let ((ds (find-definition-sources s)))
          (when (and ds (listp ds))
            (loop for (nil sn) in ds
              for snt = (source-note-text sn)
              when snt do (progn
                            (terpri)
                            (princ snt)
                            (terpri)))))))))
```

As you can see, it can retrieve itself (and more):

```
? (retrieve-source-code)

(defun retrieve-source-code (&optional (package *package*))
    (do-symbols (s package)
      (multiple-value-bind (symbol where)
                           (find-symbol (symbol-name s)
                                        package)
        (declare (ignore symbol))
        (when (member where '(:internal :external))
          (let ((ds (find-definition-sources s)))
            (when (and ds (listp ds))
              (loop for (nil sn) in ds
                for snt = (source-note-text sn)
                when snt do (progn
                              (terpri)
                              (princ snt)
                              (terpri)))))))))
NIL
```

Comment: I must say I honestly did not expect this question to be answered.