# View or Extract the text definitions entered into the top level REPL, ideally for Clozure Common Lisp (CCL)

Tags: common-lisp, ccl

When working in a top level REPL, I sometimes forget what definitions I've entered into the running lisp system.

I use Clozure CL and it provides the option of saving the application as an image, which I do and can continue where I left off, but at this point it becomes impossible to review all the code, unless I had separately typed and saved the code to xyz file already.

**Is there a way to get/extract/view the definitions that I entered, so I can save them as a source file?**

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is the [`DRIBBLE`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_dribbl.htm) function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505734/retrieving-loaded-source-code-from-ccl

Comment: @jkiiski That's a great pointer. Even though it doesn't do exactly what I need, I can see uses for it.

Comment: @RainerJoswig That's exactly it! I used the solution in the link successfully. It doesn't seem to return the global vars at the top level however. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The following will extract all the function definitions entered in a package:

```
(defun get-all-symbols (&optional package)
  (let ((lst nil)
        (package (find-package package)) )
    (do-all-symbols (s lst)
      (when (fboundp s)
        (unless (and package (not (eql (symbol-package s) package)))
          (push (cons s (function-lambda-expression s)) lst) )))))
```

Try something like:

```
(get-all-symbols *package*)
```

Comment: After entering the definition and then running (get-all-symbols) causes an error "The value GET-ALL-SYMBOLS is not of the expected type FUNCTION." Seems like it should run to me, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Suggested: `
(defun get-all-symbols (&optional package)
           (let ((list nil)
                 (package (find-package package)) )
             (do-all-symbols (s list)
               (when (fboundp s)
                 (unless (and package (not (eql (symbol-package s) package)))
                   (let ((def (function-lambda-expression (coerce s 'function)))) 
                     (when def (push (list* 'defun s def) list))))))))`

Answer (score 2):

Common Lisp (in general) does not provide any standard way to “recover” the source code of a definition once it has been compiled. Normally, it's found in whatever file or buffer you're working-from.

(As Leo's answer points out, there is `Function-Lambda-Expression`, which *can* give you some function definitions. It won't help with, say, constants or classes, and it won't always work — as CLHS says, “Any implementation may legitimately return nil as the lambda-expression of any function.” http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_fn_lam.htm — his solution is certainly useful in the most common case(s), but it is not “as general” as this one.)

You could use a set of “wrapper” macros which store the forms you pass to them in a global hash-table, and then recover the source from that. Writing that sounded like an interesting little challenge, so the below is my attempt to do something like that.

### My Silly Wrappers Solution

Note that the “source” forms stashed in this way won't preserve reader macros, comments, or the like, and will probably choke on some things like `defmethod` in subtly horrible ways. That's because I blindly store the definitions keyed off the defining form — eg, `defun` — and the second word, only. It's not smart enough to notice if you rebound a function as a macro or generic function (all three conflicting definitions would be saved), it doesn't read method combinations or lambda lists to save various methods, or any of that. There are lots of other things you might do — eg, `(SetF (FDefinition 'FOO) …)` — that could bypass these and go unnoticed, so it's far from “foolproof.” *Caveat Lector*.

The macros here try to inherit the documentation and lambda lists from the underlying forms, so they should work pretty nicely with most IDE's. They do well enough, in Slime.

One way to work with these would be to directly call them; eg, in your REPL you could directly

```
 My-Package> (use-package :wrap-defining-form)
 My-Package> (defun$ my-fn (x) (+ x (sqrt x)))
```

A more dangerous/interesting way is provided in the package `Wrap-Defining-Form.Shadowing`, in which the macros shadow the real `Common-Lisp` package definitions …

```
 CL-User> (in-package :CL-USER$)
 CL-User$> (defun blah (n) (loop repeat n do (format t "~&Blah …")))
```

When you're ready to “save” things, run `(dump-definitions)`.

I wrote and tested this in SBCL, but tried to take care that it should work on many/most other implementations. In particular, I used one non-ANSI function: `SB-Introspect:Function-Lambda-List`. The function here `Wrap-Defining-Form::Find-Function-Lambda-List` will search all packages for your implementation's version of that function. If it can't find one, all is not lost; but you won't get hints from your IDE about the lambda-list of the wrapped function. (Clozure's seems to work — kinda — for functions, but not macros. That can probably be improved.)

```
CL-USER> (describe 'defun$)
WRAP-DEFINING-FORM:DEFUN$
  [symbol]

DEFUN$ names a macro:
  Lambda-list: (NAME LAMBDA-LIST &BODY BODY)
  Documentation:
    Wrap `DEFUN' and save the original form.

    DEFUN: Define a function at top level.
  Source file: /home/brpocock/Private/wrap-defining-form.lisp
; No value
```

Without Function-Lambda-List, the wrapper looks like

```
  Lambda-list: (&REST UNKNOWN-LAMBDA-LIST)
```

… which is not very helpful.

---

### wrap-defining-form.lisp

EDIT: Debugged in Clozure. Posted to https://github.com/brpocock/wrap-defining-forms also.

```
;;;; Wrap--Defining-Forms
;;; -*- Lisp -*-

(defpackage wrap-defining-forms
  (:use :common-lisp)
  (:documentation "Wrap  defining forms so  that they (try to)  save the
  source code of the definition being passed.")
  (:export #:wrap-defining-form #:dump-definitions

           #:defclass$
           #:defconstant$
           #:defgeneric$
           #:define-compiler-macro$
           #:define-condition$
           #:define-method-combination$
           #:define-modify-macro$
           #:define-setf-expander$
           #:define-symbol-macro$
           #:defmacro$
           #:defmethod$
           #:defpackage$
           #:defparameter$
           #:defsetf$
           #:defstruct$
           #:deftype$
           #:defun$
           #:defvar$))

(defpackage wrap-defining-forms.shadowing
  (:documentation "Wrapped forms like DEFUN$  are exported here with the
  names   of   the    forms   that   they   wrap,    like   DEFUN,   for
  shadowing imports.")
  (:export #:defclass
           #:defconstant
           #:defgeneric
           #:define-compiler-macro
           #:define-condition
           #:define-method-combination
           #:define-modify-macro
           #:define-setf-expander
           #:define-symbol-macro
           #:defmacro
           #:defmethod
           #:defpackage
           #:defparameter
           #:defsetf
           #:defstruct
           #:deftype
           #:defun
           #:defvar)
  (:use))

;; Clozure appears  to be  “smart” and adds  Common-Lisp even  though we
;; didn't ask for it (and explicily don't want it)
#+ccl (unuse-package '(:ccl :common-lisp)
                     :wrap-defining-forms.shadowing)

(defpackage :common-lisp-user/save-defs
  (:nicknames :cl-user$)
  (:use :common-lisp :common-lisp-user)
  (:import-from :wrap-defining-forms #:dump-definitions)
  (:shadowing-import-from :wrap-defining-forms.shadowing
                          #:defclass
                          #:defconstant
                          #:defgeneric
                          #:define-compiler-macro
                          #:define-condition
                          #:define-method-combination
                          #:define-modify-macro
                          #:define-setf-expander
                          #:define-symbol-macro
                          #:defmacro
                          #:defmethod
                          #:defpackage
                          #:defparameter
                          #:defsetf
                          #:defstruct
                          #:deftype
                          #:defun
                          #:defvar))
;; Clone any other functions you may have packed into CL-User.
(with-package-iterator (next-symbol :common-lisp-user :internal)
  (loop for symbol = (next-symbol) 
        while symbol
        for sibling = (intern (symbol-name symbol) (find-package :cl-user$))
        when (and (fboundp symbol)
                  (not (fboundp sibling)))
          do (setf (fdefinition sibling) (fdefinition symbol))))
(in-package "WRAP-DEFINING-FORMS")

(defvar *definitions* (make-hash-table)
  "Copies   of    forms   defined    by   the   wrappers    created   by
  `WRAP-DEFINING-FORM' which can be stashed with `DUMP-DEFINITIONS'")

#+ccl
(defun ccl-mock-lambda-list (function)
  (if (macro-function function)
      (list '&rest 'macro-lambda-list)
      (multiple-value-bind (required optional restp
                            keywords) 
          (ccl:function-args (fdefinition function))
        (concatenate ' list
                       (loop repeat required 
                             collect (gensym "ARG-"))
                       (when (and optional (plusp optional))
                         (cons '&optional
                               (loop repeat optional
                                     collect (gensym "OPT-"))))
                       (when restp
                         (list '&rest 'rest))
                       (when (and keywords (plusp keywords))
                         (list '&key '&allow-other-keys))))))

(defun find-function-lambda-list ()
  "Find the implementation's version  of `FUNCTION-LAMBDA-LIST' if there
is  one.  That  way,  Slime  and  friends  can  still  give  the  proper
lambda-list  for the  wrapped form.  If it  can't be  found, this  will
return a stub with just a &rest-var."
  (or
   #+sbcl #'sb-introspect:function-lambda-list
   #+ccl #'ccl-mock-lambda-list
   #-(or ccl sbcl)
   (dolist (package (list-all-packages))
     (let ((sym (find-symbol "FUNCTION-LAMBDA-LIST" package)))
       (when (fboundp sym)
         (return-from find-function-lambda-list sym)))) 
   (lambda (function)
     (declare (ignore function))
     (list '&rest 'unknown-lambda-list))))

(defmacro wrap-defining-form (cl-form) 
  "Assuming  that CL-FORM  is a  symbol for  a macro  or function  which
defines something  interesting (eg, “Defun”),  this will create  a macro
with the same  name with a trailing  “$” that will save  the source tree
before passing on the form to CL-FORM.

EG:  (wrap-defining-form  defun)  provides  a  “defun$”  which  has  the
additional side effect of storing the source form in *DEFINITIONS*.

Definitions saved can be recovered by `DUMP-DEFINITIONS'.

This  is not  industrial-strength; in  particular, I  expect it  to cope
poorly with DEFMETHOD."
  (check-type cl-form symbol)
  (let ((wrapper (intern (concatenate 'string (symbol-name cl-form) "$")))
        (wrapper.shadow (intern (symbol-name cl-form) :wrap-defining-forms.shadowing))
        (wrapped-lambda-list (funcall (find-function-lambda-list) 'defun)))
    (setf (gethash cl-form *definitions*) (make-hash-table))
    `(prog1
         (defmacro ,wrapper (&whole whole ,@wrapped-lambda-list)
           (declare (ignore ,@(remove-if (lambda (form) (member form lambda-list-keywords))
                                         wrapped-lambda-list)))
           ,(concatenate 'string "Wrap `" (symbol-name cl-form) "' and save the original form." #(#\newline #\newline)
                         (symbol-name cl-form) ": " (or (documentation cl-form 'function)
                                                        "(see CLHS; no documentation here)"))
           (let ((defined (cons ',cl-form (cdr whole))))
             (setf (gethash (second whole) (gethash ',cl-form *definitions*))
                   defined)
             defined))
       (defmacro ,wrapper.shadow (&whole whole ,@wrapped-lambda-list)
         (declare (ignore ,@(remove-if (lambda (form) (member form lambda-list-keywords))
                                       wrapped-lambda-list)))
         ,(concatenate 'string "Wrap `COMMON-LISP:" (symbol-name cl-form) "' and save the original form."
                       #(#\newline #\newline)
                       (symbol-name cl-form) ": " (or (documentation cl-form 'function)
                                                      "(see CLHS; no documentation here)"))
         (let ((defined (cons ',cl-form (cdr whole))))
           (setf (gethash (second whole) (gethash ',cl-form *definitions*)) 
                 defined)
           defined)))))
(wrap-defining-form defclass)
(wrap-defining-form defconstant)
(wrap-defining-form defgeneric)
(wrap-defining-form define-compiler-macro)
(wrap-defining-form define-condition)
(wrap-defining-form define-method-combination)
(wrap-defining-form define-modify-macro)
(wrap-defining-form define-setf-expander)
(wrap-defining-form define-symbol-macro)
(wrap-defining-form defmacro)
(wrap-defining-form defmethod)
(wrap-defining-form defpackage)
(wrap-defining-form defparameter)
(wrap-defining-form defsetf)
(wrap-defining-form defstruct)
(wrap-defining-form deftype)
(wrap-defining-form defun)
(wrap-defining-form defvar)
(defun dump-definitions (&optional pathname)
  "Write  out   the  definitions  saved   by  `WRAP-DEFINING-FORM'-built
wrappers to PATHNAME (or *STANDARD-OUTPUT*)."
  (let (output
        (*print-case* :capitalize)
        ;; If writing to file, set margin at 79, but try to keep things under 72.
        (*print-right-margin* (if pathname 79 *print-right-margin*))
        (*print-miser-width* (if pathname 72 *print-miser-width*)))
    (unwind-protect
         (progn (setq output (if pathname
                                 (open pathname :direction :output
                                                :if-exists :rename
                                                :if-does-not-exist :create)
                                 *standard-output*))
                (multiple-value-bind  (sec min hr d m y) (decode-universal-time (get-universal-time))
                  (declare (ignore sec))
                  (format output
                          "~&~|~%;;; definitions as of ~d-~d-~d @ ~d:~2,'0d:
\(In-Package #:~a)
~{~{~2%~:<~W ~@_~:I~W ~:_~W~1I ~_~W~:>~}~^~|~}~%~|~%" ; from CLHS 22.2.2 SIMPLE-PPRINT-DEFUN
                          y m d hr min
                          (package-name *package*)
                          (remove-if #'null
                                     (loop for form being the hash-keys of *definitions*
                                           for defs = (gethash form *definitions*)
                                           collect (loop for definition being the hash-values of defs
                                                         collect definition))))))
      (when output (ignore-errors (close output))))))
```

---

### Sample Usage

```
CL-USER> (load "wrap-defining-form.lisp")

T
CL-USER> (use-package :wrap-defining-form)
T
CL-USER> (defun$ trash-word (word) 
           (let ((s (string word)))
             (sort (remove-if-not #'alpha-char-p s) #'char<)))
WARNING: redefining COMMON-LISP-USER::TRASH-WORD in DEFUN
TRASH-WORD
CL-USER> (trash-word 'Blatherscythe)
"ABCEEHHLRSTTY"
CL-USER> (describe 'trash-word)
COMMON-LISP-USER::TRASH-WORD
  [symbol]

TRASH-WORD names a compiled function:
  Lambda-list: (WORD)
  Derived type: (FUNCTION (T) (VALUES SEQUENCE &OPTIONAL))
  Source form:
    (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA TRASH-WORD
        (WORD)
      (BLOCK TRASH-WORD
        (LET ((S (STRING WORD)))
          (SORT (REMOVE-IF-NOT #'ALPHA-CHAR-P S) #'CHAR<))))
; No value

CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(defun$ trash-word (word) 
           (let ((s (string word)))
             (sort (remove-if-not #'alpha-char-p s) #'char<))))
(DEFUN TRASH-WORD (WORD)
  (LET ((S (STRING WORD)))
    (SORT (REMOVE-IF-NOT #'ALPHA-CHAR-P S) #'CHAR<)))
T
CL-USER>  (dump-definitions)
```

---

```
;;; definitions as of 2016-12-1 @ 15:23:
(In-Package #:COMMON-LISP-USER)

(Defun Trash-Word (Word)
  (Let ((S (String Word)))
    (Sort (Remove-If-Not #'Alpha-Char-P S) #'Char<)))
```

---

```
NIL
CL-USER> (in-package :Common-Lisp-User/Save-Defs)
#<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER/SAVE-DEFS">
CL-USER$> (defun 2+ (n) (+ 2 n))
2+
CL-USER$> (describe '2+)
COMMON-LISP-USER/SAVE-DEFS::2+
  [symbol]

2+ names a compiled function:
  Lambda-list: (N)
  Derived type: (FUNCTION (T) (VALUES NUMBER &OPTIONAL))
  Source form:
    (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA 2+
        (N)
      (BLOCK 2+ (+ 2 N)))
; No value
CL-USER$> (macroexpand-1 '(defun 2+ (n) (+ 2 n)))
(COMMON-LISP:DEFUN 2+ (N) (+ 2 N))
T
CL-USER$> (documentation 'defun 'function)
"Wrap `COMMON-LISP:DEFUN' and save the original form.

DEFUN: Define a function at top level."

CL-USER$> (dump-definitions)
```

---

```
;;; definitions as of 2016-12-1 @ 15:32:
(In-Package #:COMMON-LISP-USER/SAVE-DEFS)


(Common-Lisp:Defun 2+ (N) (+ 2 N))

(Common-Lisp:Defun Trash-Word (Word)
  (Let ((S (String Word)))
    (Sort (Remove-If-Not #'Alpha-Char-P S) #'Char<)))
```

---

```
    NIL
```

---

### File Backup

`Dump-Definitions` also will write to a file. (It sets `:If-Exists :Rename`, so you could have one-level-UNDO protection as well.)

```
     CL-USER$> (dump-definitions "saved.lisp")
     NIL
```

Comment: I did hack a little more on the GitHub version, qv.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can easily implement something like this yourself:

```
(defun my-repl (&optional (file-path "cl-history.lisp"))
  "Saves commands to a file"
  (loop
    (with-open-file (stream file-path
                            :direction :output
                            :if-does-not-exist :create
                            :if-exists :append) 
      (print '>)
      (let ((input (read)))
        (format stream "~A~%" input)
        (print (eval input))))))
```

To exit the inner loop you should type `(quit)`.

Alternatively you can use [`com.informatimago.common-lisp.interactive.interactive:repl`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.lisp/FcE0CnjqEu4)

Comment: What an innovative way to do it! I tried this, however calling (my-repl "temp.file") does create a temp.file at the specified location, but it is always 0 bytes. Somehow nothing is written to it. I entered a bunch of definitions and when you inspect them, the source note does say (my-repl "temp.file") as the source, but temp.file has nothing in it.

Comment: The "way" is borrowed from Land of Lisp and Artificial Intelligence Programming. Both books are highly recommended. :) I fixed the function and added the file name as optional argument so you don't have to type it every time (I suppose you want to reuse a file). However I advice you to use emacs with SLIME :) You will never need to use such tools once you configure it and install it. Alternatively you can use LispWorks. I haven't delved into it as it is quite expensive for me, but I hear it is really good.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interactive session with CCL:

```
? (declaim (optimize (debug 3)))
NIL
```

The above is not strictly required here, but it doesn't hurt to develop with high debugging levels.

```
? (defun foo (x) (+ 3 x))
FOO
? (inspect 'foo)
[0]     FOO
[1]     Type: SYMBOL
[2]     Class: #<BUILT-IN-CLASS SYMBOL>
        Function
[3]     INTERNAL in package: #<Package "COMMON-LISP-USER">
[4]     Print name: "FOO"
[5]     Value: #<Unbound>
[6]     Function: #<Compiled-function FOO #x3020004B3F7F>
[7]     Arglist: (X)
[8]     Plist: NIL
Inspect> 6
[0]     #<Compiled-function FOO #x3020004B3F7F>
[1]     Name: FOO
[2]     Arglist (analysis): (X)
[3]     Bits: 8388864
[4]     Plist: (CCL::PC-SOURCE-MAP #(17 70 15 22) CCL::FUNCTION-SYMBOL-MAP
        (#(X) . #(63 17 70)) CCL::%FUNCTION-SOURCE-NOTE ...)
[5]     Source Location: #<SOURCE-NOTE Interactive "(defun foo (x) (+ 3 x))">
Inspect 1> 5
[0]     #<SOURCE-NOTE Interactive "(defun foo (x) (+ 3 x))">
[1]     Type: SOURCE-NOTE
[2]     Class: #<STRUCTURE-CLASS SOURCE-NOTE>
[3]     SOURCE: #(40 100 101 102 117 ...)
[4]     FILENAME: NIL
[5]     FILE-RANGE: 23
```

You can see that even from within the REPL, and without running Slime which might also store information about the Emacs environment, you can have access to the source code of FOO. This can be used if you know which function you want to recover. For a recording of your interactive session, follow [jkiiski's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902449/view-or-extract-the-text-definitions-entered-into-the-top-level-repl-ideally-fo/40906545#comment69018897_40902449) about DRIBBLE.